# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined using react-chartjs.min.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am very new to react.js. pardon me if the question is too silly
i would want to build a line chart. i have decided to go ahead with react.js ,chart.js and react-chartjs.min.js.

I have included the script for react-chartjs.min in my cshtml, i have also added jsx file in the same.

Now im facing a error , i dont where i am going wrong.

1. demo.jsx gives - Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

   ### index.cshtml

```
<div id="content" class="myDiv" ></div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/react.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/remarkable.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-chartjs/0.8.0/react-chartjs.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser-polyfill.js"></script>

 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Custom/demo.jsx")"></script>
</div>
```

### demo.jsx

var LineChart = require("react-chartjs").Line;

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./Scripts/Custom/OrderReleaseItems.jsx",
    output: {
        filename: "./dist/bundle.js"
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: ".",
        host: "localhost",
        port: 15878
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    }, plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                'React': 'react',
                '$': 'jquery',
                '_': 'lodash',
                'ReactDOM': 'react-dom',
                'cssModule': 'react-css-modules',
                'Promise': 'bluebird'
            })

    ]
};
```

Comment: is there a way to install webpack without using npm command?

Answer (score 0):

you have to import Line as mentioned in example of react-chartjs

[example code](https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2/blob/master/example/src/components/line.js#L2)

```
import {Line} from 'react-chartjs-2';
```

Also you have to use bable for building this.

Comment: i would be using es5 and not es6. Is it not possible to use es5 and use react-chartjs-2?